# Create Google Contact with Node.js and Service Account

Tags: node.js, api, google-api, google-contacts-api, service-accounts

I would like to create a script to be scheduled in a **.bat** file that automatically links to google contacts and creates contacts read in a **Mysql Database**.

I would like a system that does not require any user action.

 
I know that **service-account** exist but I have no idea how to create the program. Do you know how to do it?

I hope you can give me a hand.

For the moment, I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in three steps if the user is not part of G Suite.

1. Authenticate the user using OAuth with `access_type = offline`.
2. Save the generated Refresh Token.
3. Use the Refresh Token to generate a new Access Token and then update the account's contacts. The Access Token will be valid (default) for 3,600 seconds.

If the user is part of G Suite, then enable Domain Wide Delegation on a service account and impersonate the user.